# What is the alternative for ALL and EVERY in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, subquery, inner-join

Hey im new to SQL and I'm trying to find the names of students enrolled in the maximum number of classes using SQLite on sqliteonline.com

These are the relations:

[image]

This is what I have:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Student S
WHERE S.snum IN (SELECT E.snum
                 FROM Enrolled E
                 GROUP BY E.snum
                 HAVING COUNT (*) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT (*)
                 FROM Enrolled E2
                 GROUP BY E2.snum ))
```

AND this is the error that I get:

[image]

I'm guessing the ALL keyword doesn't exist in SQLite or is used differently so I'm wondering what I should do next.

I'm also having the same problem with the EVERY keyword.

What I'm trying to solve:
For each faculty member that has taught classes only in room R128, print the faculty
member's name and the total number of classes she or he has taught.

What I have:

```
SELECT F.fname, COUNT(*) AS CourseCount
FROM Faculty F, Class C
WHERE F.fid = C.fid
GROUP BY F.fid, F.fname
HAVING EVERY ( C.room = "R128" )
```

What I get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Student S
WHERE S.snum IN (SELECT E.snum
                 FROM Enrolled E
                 GROUP BY E.snum
                 HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM Enrolled E2
                                    GROUP BY E2.snum 
                                    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
                                    LIMIT 1
                                   )
                );
```

Note:  There are other ways to express the query logic.  This specifically addresses the question that you asked.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses window functions:

```
select s.name
from student s
inner join (
    select snum, rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from enrolled e
    group by snum
) e on e.snum = s.snum
where rn = 1
```

If your version of SQLite does not support window functions (which were added in version 3.25), I would recommend a join and filtering with a `having` clause:

```
select s.name
from students s
inner join enrolled e on e.snum = s.snum
group by s.snum, s.name
having count(*) = (
    select count(*)
    from enrolled
    group by snum
    order by count(*) desc limit 1
)
```